# Adding a WordPieceTokenizer to a keras end-to-end model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have trained a simple classification model based on https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_from_scratch that uses a `WordPieceTokenizer` & `StartEndPacker` to pre-process the input strings.  Everything works great, now I would like to export the model for use elsewhere.

Based on the `make an end-to-end model` bit of the tutorial, I should be able to just add my tokenizer/packer to the model and hit run, right?

```py
tokenizer = keras_nlp.tokenizers.WordPieceTokenizer(...)
start_packer = keras_nlp.layers.StartEndPacker(...)
...
# A string input
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), ragged=True, dtype="string")
# Turn strings into vocab indices
indices = tokenizer(inputs)
packed = start_packer(indices)
# Turn vocab indices into predictions
outputs = model(packed)
# profit
end_to_end_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
outputs = end_to_end_model.predict([
    "JumbleOText",
    "nvagonnagesthis",
    "Written for a Human"
])
```

Unfortunately, the `start_packer` throws

```
ValueError: Input must either be rank 1 or rank 2. Received input with rank=3
```

I am (very) new to this, and I'm not sure why this is happening.  From what I understand,
the input takes in a 1-dim vector (ie, a single string).  According to [this github comment](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-nlp/issues/49#issuecomment-1078422078), a 1-dim input should map to a 2-dim output, no?  When stepping through the code the `inputs` have a shape of `TensorShape([None, 1])`, which seems to be rank 2 (explaining my error), but I just don't get why that would be the shape of the `Input`, and if that is the issue, what I can do to fix it?

Comment: No, it was PoC so I just duplicated the pre-processing in the target app